# How can I create this layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I've been trying to recreate this layout in **Android Studio** (*API 19*) without success.

I added at the top part of the image what I need without texts on it, the part below has some explanations.

[image]

Every time I tried (no matter `LinearLayout` or `GridLayout`), the text in the middle broke the design if it is long or if I do not set real DP size (like using `wrap_content`), if the text has a fixed size I must adapt it to every screen size on both, vertical and horizontal, which I don't want, because I must update a lot of files it every time I make changes on layouts, and if it has `wrap_content` and the text is long the switch goes off of the screen.

I made this "design" with Photoshop of what I need to recreate on Android Studio on a layout (*xml only, not programmatically*), if possible I'd like `LinearLayout` or `GridLayout` or both, I don't care how much sub-layouts are needed.

*Additional: If someone knows how to get that switch style for older versions of Android, it'd be really good to get the same style on that too, but is not necessary.*

Please help me, I really can't make it, thanks a lot.

Comment: that's toggle button, what minimum version of Android are you considering? POST CODE - What you have tried so far?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following XML as your layout codes, this is exactly what you want on your designs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_paypal"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/switchlayout"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text 1"
        android:textColor="#000"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text 2"
        android:textColor="#ccc"
        />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/switchlayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="72dp">
    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

With a Relative Layout this kind of design wont be a problem.

You will need to use the properties android:layout_alignParentRight and android:layout_alignParentLeft.

Your center textview will use android:layout_toRightOf and ndroid:layout_toLeftOf.

More informations : [Relative layout documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

Comment: Also, the middle layout with the text could be a vertical linear layout, which would allow `Text 1` to occupy its own space and `Text 2` to occupy its own space, but be positioned below `Text 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Follow XML code. it will fit in any screen

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".2"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/app_icon" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".6">
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".2"
    android:gravity="center">
    <Switch
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```